# jQuery skipping content between "<>" in Split function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question:

Why does this

```
var string = 'John Doe <john@doe.com>, Jane Doe <jane@doe.com>'

var splitString = string.split(',');

$.each(splitString, function(number) {
    console.log(splitString[number]);
});
```

produce

```
John Doe
Jane Doe
```

instead of

```
John Doe <john@doe.com>
Jane Doe <jane@doe.com>
```

It seems like jQuery is skipping the email address between the `<` `>` tags. Does anybody know why? And - more importantly - how to force jQuery to include this content?

Thank you!

Comment: When you `console.log` out the `splitString` before your `jquery.each` usage, what do you see?

Comment: It [works as expected here](https://jsfiddle.net/t2kqf1p7/)..

Comment: (It's because he's splitting a different variable than the one he's defined)

Comment: sorry guys, I pasted the wrong variable. @JoshCrozier Thanks! you're right, I need to take another look at my code ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the navigator interpretates the content of < ... > as a tag and therefor, no like text to show... you could find it and replace it with ist code (< & # 60; and > & # 62;)

```
var string = 'John Doe &#60;john@doe.com&#62;, Jane Doe &#60;jane@doe.com&#60;'

var splitString = string.split(',');

$.each(splitString, function(number) {
    console.log(splitString[number]);
});
```

you could replace it in your data or do it while reading with [JavaScript String replace() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)...